# Could clones be Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, clones

I am referring specifically to clones of Jango Fett from *Attack of the Clones*. Could one or more of these clones, from an original that is **not** Force-sensitive be Force-sensitive, without any genetic modifications (by chance)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the EU Palpatine made force sensitive clones and transfered his soul to them using the Dark side as a means of immortality.

Comment: @Loki, I made my question more specific

Comment: Given that the clones were simply using the DNA of Jango (the original) and he was not Force sensitive I think it is safe to assume that none of his "replicates" were either. Though, while blood lines help in this regard, it is not mandatory, so I think it is possible... but even if one or more was sensitive the significant psychological conditioning, inhibitor chips, etc. would have suppressed any motivation to pursue their paths and they likely would have only been able to be uniquely successful on the battlefield and promoted to commander positions or something similar.

Comment: There is a non-canon version enhanced by lightsaber crystals: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jek-14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know, the clone troopers engineered from Jango Fett never became Force-sensitive. Most likely the symbiosis with Midi-chlorians could not be created in a laboratory.

In Legends, however, there were a couple of Force-sensitive clone troopers, who were created from different template, a Jedi knight. The troopers, codenamed [X1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X1) and [X2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X2) were secretly cloned from the DNA of [Falon Grey](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Falon_Grey), and they did possess Force powers.

The characters were created for the video game [Star Wars Battlefront: Elite Squadron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront:_Elite_Squadron), in 2009.

Comment: Don't forget Dorsk 82: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dorsk_82